# using cv2 for shape recoginition

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm having problem with my code, it's supposed to get a two line input, the first line is how many shapes are in the image, and the second line is the image path.

The output should be the number of types of shapes, example input: there is a test1.jpg image that has 10 circles in it, the output should be: 1

here's the code someone came up with using kernel :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def detect_shape(cnt):
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.04 * peri, True)  # Approximate the polygonal curves
    if len(vertices) == 3:
        return "Triangle"
    elif len(vertices) == 4:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(vertices)
        aspect_ratio = float(w) / h
        if 0.95 <= aspect_ratio <= 1.05:
            return "Square"
        else:
            return "Rectangle"
    else:
        return "Circle"

num_shapes = int(input("Enter the number of shapes in the image: "))
image_path = input("Enter the path to the image: ")


image = cv2.imread(image_path)


gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
inv_binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

kernel = 255*np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8) # dilate the binary mask, here and next line
dilated_binary = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)

mask = cv2.dilate((dilated_binary < 245).astype(np.uint8)*255, kernel, iterations=1) # create another binary mask where the values are lower than 245, here I did some manual checking

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # find the contour on the mask

filtered_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100] # filter the contours

circles = 0 
triangles = 0 
rectangles = 0  
for contour in filtered_contours:
        M = cv2.moments(contour)
        if M["m00"] != 0:
            cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        # approximate the contour
        epsilon = 0.04 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
        # number of sides
        num_vertices = len(approx)
        # see how many sides and decide which shape
        if num_vertices == 3:
            shape = "Triangle"
            triangles += 1
        elif num_vertices == 4:
            shape = "Rectangle"
            rectangles += 1
        else: # in this case I just put the default as a circle, since there are currently no other options.
            shape = "Circle"
            circles += 1
        plt.text(cx, cy, shape)
         
print("Summary:") 
print("Rects or squares: "+str(rectangles)) 
print("Triangles: "+str(triangles))
print("Circles: "+str(circles))

cv2.imshow('adjusted', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but there is one problem with only one image I couldn't figure it out

so if you give this image [image: this image] as input , it wont work correctly : [image]

Comment: After thresholding & morphology, those shapes don't really look like triangles anymore, do they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better threshold results by thresholding on the background gray color in the original image using Python/OpenCV cv2.inRange() then invert. Or convert to HSV and threshold on the saturation channel where the gray background will have very low saturation and the color regions a higher saturation

For example, here is the saturation channel:

[image]

And here is a threshold on the saturation channel:

[image]

And here is an inverted color threshold on the background color from the input:

[image]